# Mirror mysql table structure

Tags: php, mysql, database

How would someone maintain different tables that share a similar structure:

Example: I have 600 tables with 20 fields and I've been using this structure for months, what if I need to delete 1 field and add 2 new ones, how could it possibly be done just by changing a master table which contains the structure that must be used by all of the other cloned tables?

Comment: What scripting languages are you familiar with?

Comment: Why haven't you created just a single table as long as all of them have the same structure?

Comment: This question is unanswerable. There is no "replicate changes made to one table to other tables" function in MySQL. You should either not use 600 copies of the same table, or you will write code to apply the same `ALTER TABLE` queries to all 600.

Comment: If table structures are identical then you could automate this task.

Comment: How would I automate the task? Also, I don't want to use one table because there could be dozens of million records on these tables, that's the reason why I would want a master and its clones.

Comment: What are the names of your tables? Do they share a common prefix or suffix?

Comment: sector_modulep - sector is an id stored on a table ex: 081230_modulep imagine master being just "sector_modulep", so all sectors that are on the table that holds the ids (19328109,9120829,etc) should be affected every time alter table is done to sector_modulep, in this case 19328109_modulep and the other one if it were just those two cloned tables from sector_modulep - the idea is to create sectors for modules out of a master table.

Comment: _modulep is the common suffix

Answer (score 0):

Well, you probably know that your structure is far from being optimal and the best solution is to reorganise it. It is not always easy with legacy systems though, so the task can be still performed with MySQL only.

You will need "cursors" there which can be only used inside stored procedures, so you'll need to create a stored procedure first (its sample code is below) and then to execute is as `CALL alter_many_tables()`;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE alter_many_tables()
BEGIN
    -- reading names of the table to update in a cursor
    DECLARE tables_cursor CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            `TABLE_NAME`
        FROM
            `information_schema`.`columns`
        WHERE
            `TABLE_NAME` LIKE '%\_modulep'
    ;

    -- condition for the loop over found tables to stop
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    -- looping
    read_loop: LOOP
        -- reading table name into a variable
        FETCH tables_cursor INTO table_name;

        -- check if the loop is over
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        -- forming a table update SQL (modify it as you need)
        SET @sql = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', @table_name, ' ADD COLUMN `new_column` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL');

        -- executing the SQL we have composed above
        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE stmt;
     END LOOP;

     -- closing the cursor
     CLOSE table_cursor;
END;
```

There might be some minor syntax errors in the snippet above as I can't test at the moment, but you get the idea.